# Error While installing PyAudio in macOS: How can I fix this problem?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I was trying to install PyAudio
The system is macOS Mojave, and version of Python is 3.8

I think pip doesn't have any problem, but some frameworks are collided with pyaudio

here are error message shown.
What should I do?

```
pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-install-b7gmavn1/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-install-b7gmavn1/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-record-zz9o5bbq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyaudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-install-b7gmavn1/pyaudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-install-b7gmavn1/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-install-b7gmavn1/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hq/cp10yz710x51x0qsxlrj5s5m0000gn/T/pip-record-zz9o5bbq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Ah, I have solved this problem for myself
Before installing, portaudio was prerequisite library
so
brew install portaudio 
pip install pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pipwin first using:

```
 pip install pipwin
```

and then install Pyaudio using pipwin:

```
 pipwin install PyAudio
```